# How much data can R handle?

Tags: r, large-data

By "handle" I mean manipulate multi-columnar rows of data. How does R stack up against tools like Excel, SPSS, SAS, and others? Is R a viable tool for looking at "BIG DATA" (hundreds of millions to billions of rows)? If not, which statistical programming tools are best suited for analysis large data sets?

Comment: As long as you don't store it to RAM, you can churn through virtually endless data using any language (Python).

Comment: Stick with Excel, it is web-scale. Oh, wait, am I two days late?

Comment: Excel can't handle CSV files with more than one million rows.

Answer (score 18):

If you look at the [High-Performance Computing Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) on CRAN, you will get a good idea of what R can do in a sense of high performance.

Answer (score 11):

You can in principal store as much data as you have RAM with the **exception** that, currently, vectors and matrices are restricted to 2^31 - 1 elements because R uses 32-bit indexes on vectors. General vectors (lists, and their derivative data frames) are restricted to 2^31 - 1 components, and each of those components has the same restrictions as vectors/matrices/lists/data.frames etc.

Of course these are theoretical limits, if you want to do anything with data in R it will inevitably require space to hold a couple of copies at least, as R will usually copy data passed in to functions etc.

There are efforts to allow on disk storage (rather than in RAM); but even those will be restricted to the 2^31-1 restrictions mentioned above in use in R at any one time. See the *Large memory and out-of-memory data* section of the High Performance Computing Task View linked to in @Roman's post.

Comment: 2^31 is about 2.1GB

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a good indication of its suitability for "big data" is the fact that R has emerged as the platform of choice for developers competing in Kaggle.com data modeling competitions.  See the [article](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2011/04/how-kaggle-competitors-use-r.html) on the Revolution Analytics website -- R beats out SAS and SPSS by a healthy margin.  What R lacks in out of the box number crunching power it apparently makes up for in flexibility.

In addition to what's available on [the web](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) there are several new books for how to hot-rod R for tackling big data.  The [Art of R Programming](http://nostarch.com/artofr.htm) (Matloff 2011; No Starch Press) provide introductions to writing optimized R code, parallel computing, and using R in conjunction with C.  The entire book is well-written with great code samples and walk-throughs.  [Parallel R](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021421.do) (McCallum & Weston 2011; O'Reilly) looks good too.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain my short story with R and big data set.
I had a connector from R to RDBMS,

- where I stored 80mln compounds.

I've build a queries which gathered some subset of this data.
Then manipulate on this subset.
R was simply choking with more than **200k** rows in memory on my PC.

- core duo
- 4 GB ram

So working on some appropriate subset for machine is good approach.

Comment: Wow,.. guys which gave '-', could you please explain why?

Comment: try adding a reproducible example, perhaps using SQLite instead of a RBDMS. or create a random vector with 200k rows and see if it chokes. Or tell us how many columns does your dataset have. etc etc